# Emberjs: Accessing parent route model which is a Promise (master-detail)

Tags: ember.js, master-detail

[image]

I've got master-detail page layout as on image. I access this page through `#/masters/:master_id` app url.

Routes a defined as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('masters', { path: '/masters' }, function() {
       this.route('detail', { path: '/:master_id' });
  });
});

App.MastersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return App.DataStore.getData('/api/masters'); //returns Promise!
   },

   setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set("content", model);
   }
});

App.MastersDetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
      return this.modelFor("masters").find(function(item) {
          return item.get("id") == params.master_id;
      });
   }
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="masters">
    <div id="masters-grid">
      {{#each master in model}}
         <div {{action "show" master}}>
            {{master.name}}
         </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div id="detail">
       {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="masters/detail">
   {{model.name}} <br />
   {{model.age}} <br />
   {{model.address}} <br />
</script>
```

When clicking through masters in the grid I want to show their details in Detail outlet and I do not want to reload all masters from API when changing the master selection.

I have a problem with `MastersDetailRoute`'s model, because `this.modelFor("masters")` returns `undefined`. I think, it is caused by returning Promise in `model` hook. Any idea or workaround how to access one item from Masters model or controller in "child route" `model` hook?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things here.

- when defining routes that have the same url as the route name theres no need to specify the path
- the detail route should also be a resource as it is a route backed by a model
- In the Masters route returning a promise is correct and supported natively by ember.  The route wont be resolved until the promise is.
- setup controller isn't required
- its usually best to do the required api call to fetch the individual record in the detail route.  This will only be used when loading the page for the first time (if f5 ing or coming from a bookmark)
- in your masters template you can use id instead of typing data-template-name or better still look into use ember-cli/brocolli or grunt to precompile your templates
- to prevent ember refetching your model when selecting a row use the handlebars helper link-to

`{{#link-to 'masterDetail' master}}
    {{master.name}}
{{/link-to}}`

- just to clarify, using link-to in this way passes the object specified in the second parameter as the model to the specified route (first parameter). In your case master will now be set as the model to the master detail route.
- in masters detail theres no need to type "model" the default context (i.e. the value of "this") in your template is the controller, then if the property is not found on the controller it looks for it in the model.

Hope this helps